# Batch file to save all opened files and then shutdown system

Tags: batch-file, shutdown, autosave

I did not find a solution online, so I will ask it here.
I would like to create a batch file that will save all openend work (for example: An opened and unsaved Word document). After it saves all opened work (with added an timestamp or a text with 'autosave'), it must shutdown.

The last part I can make myself (shutdown -t 0), but the first part is too difficult for me.

Do you have any solution?

Thank you for considering my question,
ButerBreaGrieneTsiis

Comment: There is no common interface for saving a document in Windows. This is likely not possible.

Comment: Thats too bad, but if it won't work then we can nothing do about it.